# ソートされてないMultiIndexの列を持つDataFrameに対して、PerformanceWarningが発生するケースと発生しないケースの差は何でしょうか？

Tags: python, pandas

## 環境

- Python 3.11.2
- pandas 2.0.2

列がMultiIndexで、列名がソートされていないDataFrameがあります。

```
In [474]: df = pandas.DataFrame({("x","a"):[1,2,3],("y",""):["a","b","b"],("x","b"):[5,6,7]})

In [481]: df
Out[481]: 
   x  y  x
   a     b
0  1  a  5
1  2  b  6
2  3  b  7
```

y列をgroupbyで処理するとPerformanceWarningが発生しました。

```
In [486]: df.groupby("y").sum()
<ipython-input-486-d2970d0aff60>:1: PerformanceWarning: dropping on a non-lexsorted multi-index without a level parameter may impact performance.
  tmp.sum()
Out[486]: 
   x    
   a   b
y       
a  1   5
b  5  13
```

しかし、以下のコードではPerformanceWarningは発生しませんでした。

```
In [476]: df.groupby(("y","")).sum()
Out[476]: 
       x    
       a   b
(y, )       
a      1   5
b      5  13
```

## 質問

groupbyに`"y"`を指定すると警告が発生するのに、`("y","")`を指定すると警告が発生しないのはなぜでしょうか？
ソートされていないMultiIndexが問題であれば、`("y","")`を指定したときにも警告が発生すると思っていました。

## 補足

以下のブログを書いてるときに、気になった質問です。

https://qiita.com/yuji38kwmt/items/01180d451c9f2610f624

[pandasのissue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/new?assignees=&labels=Usage+Question%2CNeeds+Triage&projects=&template=submit_question.yml&title=QST%3A+)には、

> Since StackOverflow is better suited towards answering usage questions, we ask that all usage questions are first asked on StackOverflow.

と書いてあったので、まずは日本版StackOverflowで質問しました。

またバグではないような気がしたので、まだissueには報告していません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

当該のエラーメッセージは以下の `drop()` メソッドで表示されています。(引用コードの最後の部分)

[pandas/multi.py at 2.0.x · pandas-dev/pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/2.0.x/pandas/core/indexes/multi.py#L2205)

```py
def drop(  # type: ignore[override]
    self,
    codes,
    level: Index | np.ndarray | Iterable[Hashable] | None = None,
    errors: IgnoreRaise = "raise",
) -> MultiIndex:
    """
    Make new MultiIndex with passed list of codes deleted.

    Parameters
    ----------
    codes : array-like
        Must be a list of tuples when level is not specified.
    level : int or level name, default None
    errors : str, default 'raise'

    Returns
    -------
    MultiIndex
    """
    if level is not None:
        return self._drop_from_level(codes, level, errors)

    if not isinstance(codes, (np.ndarray, Index)):
        try:
            codes = com.index_labels_to_array(codes, dtype=np.dtype("object"))
        except ValueError:
            pass

    inds = []
    for level_codes in codes:
        try:
            loc = self.get_loc(level_codes)
            # get_loc returns either an integer, a slice, or a boolean
            # mask
            if isinstance(loc, int):
                inds.append(loc)
            elif isinstance(loc, slice):
                step = loc.step if loc.step is not None else 1
                inds.extend(range(loc.start, loc.stop, step))
            elif com.is_bool_indexer(loc):
                if self._lexsort_depth == 0:
                    warnings.warn(
                        "dropping on a non-lexsorted multi-index "
                        "without a level parameter may impact performance.",
                        PerformanceWarning,
                        stacklevel=find_stack_level(),
                    )
```

この `drop()` メソッドをそれぞれの場合で実行してみると `"y"` を指定した場合に当該のエラーが発生することが確認できます。

```py
>>> df.columns.drop("y")
<stdin>:1: PerformanceWarning: dropping on a non-lexsorted multi-index without a level parameter may impact performance.
MultiIndex([('x', 'a'),
            ('x', 'b')],
           )

>>> df.columns.drop(("y",""))
MultiIndex([('x', 'a'),
            ('x', 'b')],
           )

#
# "without a level parameter" との事なので、level を指定すればエラーメッセージは表示されない
# (以下のコードが実行されるので)
#
# if level is not None:
#     return self._drop_from_level(codes, level, errors)
#
>>> df.columns.drop("y", level=0)
MultiIndex([('x', 'a'),
            ('x', 'b')],
           )
```

理由は、それぞれの場合で `drop()` メソッドの内容を辿ってみると判るかと思います。

###### `df.groupby("y").sum()` の場合

```
>>> codes = com.index_labels_to_array("y", dtype=np.dtype("object"))
>>> codes
array(['y'], dtype=object)
>>> loc = df.columns.get_loc(codes[0])
>>> loc
array([False,  True, False])  # boolean array
>>> com.is_bool_indexer(loc)
True
>>> df.columns._lexsort_depth
0
```

###### `df.groupby(("y","")).sum()` の場合

```py
>> codes = com.index_labels_to_array(("y",""), dtype=np.dtype("object"))
>>> codes
array([('y', '')], dtype=object)
>>> loc = df.columns.get_loc(codes[0])
>>> loc  # int
1
>>> isinstance(loc, int)
True
```

Comment: [pandas.Index.get_loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) での挙動の違いがミソなんですね。
理解できました！ありがとうございます。